# Discrete Time Complex Exponential

Tags: python, graph, signal-processing

It does not matter how hard I am trying, I am always getting the wrong answer.
The question is to Generate a complex exponential signal using the following expression:
[]=||^() * ^()

Where =2/10 and 0≤≤100. Make two plots of only the real part of []

And the value of z is 0.5+0.02

Here is my code,

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
z = 0.5 + 0.02j
omega = (2*math.pi)/10
N = 100
x =[0] * N
for n in range(N):
    x[n] = (abs(z) ** n)* math.cos(omega*n)

plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this type of output,

[image]

But my expected output is,

[image]

Comment: Does this `[]=||^() * ^()` translate to `(abs(z) ** n)* math.cos(omega*n)` ? The first one has an exponential factor but the second one does not.

Comment: (abs(z) ** n)* math.cos(omega*n) is the real part of []=||^() * ^()

Comment: (abs(z) ** n)* math.sin(omega*n) is the imaginary part

Comment: hmm. I think it is due to the fact that the `(abs(z) ** n)` trends quickly to 0 because of 0.5**n. if the factor was 0.9**n, you will be able to see that pattern on the graph.

Comment: Your "expected output" doesn't match the equations and parameters you give.

Answer (score 0):

use stem for making discrete signal and put the N = 20 so your X-axis range will maximize and in Z change the 0.5 value to 0.7 so u will get your answer }

Above Code is changed by me so z = 0.7 + 0.02j omega = (2math.pi)/10 N = 20 x =[0] * N for n in range(N): x[n] = (abs(z) ** n) math.cos(omega*n)

plt.title('Complex Exponential |a| < 1') plt.xlabel('Samples'); plt.ylabel('Amplitude') plt.stem(x) plt.show()

Comment: Your answer could use some formatting, make sure to wrap your code in a code environment :-) Also, as I see it, there is an operator missing at `x[n] = (abs(z) ** n) math.cos(omega*n)`.